# Compare text inside custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a long table made of rows like this

```
<tr id="row_369696" class="lvtColData" bgcolor="white" onmouseout="this.className='lvtColData'" onmouseover="this.className='lvtColDataHover'">
  <td width="2%"></td>

  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    27-10-2014
    <span style="display:none;" module="Accounts" fieldname="cf_1390" recordid="369696" type="metainfo"></span>
  </td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    12:30
    <span style="display:none;" module="Accounts" fieldname="cf_1380" recordid="369696" type="metainfo"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

the end result that i need is to change the background of this row when the time and the date match the content of the columns marked by the fieldname `cf_1390` for the date part and the `cf_1380` for the time part.

i was thinking of using jquery to cycle trough rows, find the content of the cell, compare it to now date, and if it matches change the row background, but i cannot figure out how to do it.

can someone help me with some jsfiddle example ? :)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the jQuery code you have tried.

Comment: You ask for a jsFiddle and even not able to provide any sample code, hmm... FYI, you should use valid custom attributes, using `data-*`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of looping through your rows, checking if the date & time match the variables (Which i've just hard coded at the top for this example) - and then setting them to red if it finds both a date & a time match in that row.

JS:

```
var date = "27-10-2014";
var time = "12:32";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#targetTable tr').each(function(i,e){
        var match = 0;
        $(this).children('td').each(function(i2,e2){
            content = $(e2).html().substring(0, $(e2).html().indexOf('<span')).trim();
            if(content == date){ match++; }
            if(content == time){ match++; }
        });
        if(match == 2){
            $(this).css('background','red');
            $(this).children('td').css('background','red');
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MuR5M/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy-to-understand example.

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/h3Xd3/

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr id="row_369696" >
   <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    27-10-2014
    <span style="display:none;" module="Accounts" fieldname="cf_1390" recordid="369696" type="metainfo"></span>
  </td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    12:30
    <span style="display:none;" module="Accounts" fieldname="cf_1380" recordid="369696" type="metainfo"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS** `.highlight{background-color:lightgrey;}`

**JQUery**

```
function datesEqual(a, b)
{
   return (!(a>b || b>a))
}

$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("#myTable tr").each(function(){
        //Get date and hour. Split each item by the appropriate separator
        var date_row = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().split("-");
        var hour_row = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().split(":");

        var date_object = new Date(date_row[2], date_row[1] - 1, date_row[0], hour_row[0], hour_row[1]);

        var YOUR_OTHER_DATE = new Date(date_row[2], date_row[1] - 1, date_row[0], hour_row[0], hour_row[1]); //You have to change this line

        if ( datesEqual(YOUR_OTHER_DATE, date_object) == true){
            $(this).find("td").addClass("highlight");
        }

    });
});
```

**Don't forget** to change the `YOUR_OTHER_DATE` value. It depends to your need but we don't have enough details to give a complete answer.